# Iteration and concatenation in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am pretty new to XSLT and having difficulty in coding logic to iterate and concatenate using XSLT 2.0. I am providing the scenario below.

Input XML:

```
<ADR_ENTR>
    <ADR_ENTR_VW>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>LINE1</TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>LINE2</TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>LINE3</TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>LINE4</TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
    </ADR_ENTR_VW>
</ADR_ENTR>
```

There can be any number of ADR_LINE aggregates within  aggregate, and I need to output first ADR_LINE as is, then ADR_LINE 2 - 4 needs to be concatenated, then ADR_LINE 4 to last ADR_LINE needs to be concatenated.

Sample Output Response:

```
<ADR_ENTR>
    <ADR_ENTR_VW>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>LINE1</TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>LINE2 LINE3 LINE 4</TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
    </ADR_ENTR_VW>
</ADR_ENTR>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will there always be exactly 4 `<ADR_LINE>` elements in your input XML? If not, what is the expected output if there is more or less than 4?

Comment: It can be more than 4, if it's more than 4, then I need to concatenate ADR_LINE 5 to last ADR_LINE and output it. Please let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a simple template that inserts the first `<ADL_LINE>` into its own element then concatenates all the others into a second:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="ADR_ENTR/ADR_ENTR_VW">
        <ADR_ENTR>
            <ADR_ENTR_VW>
                <ADR_LINE>
                    <TEXT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ADR_LINE[1]"/>
                    </TEXT>
                </ADR_LINE>
                <ADR_LINE>
                    <TEXT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(ADR_LINE[position()!=1],' ')"/>
                    </TEXT>
                </ADR_LINE>
            </ADR_ENTR_VW>
        </ADR_ENTR>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This line selects the first `<ADR_LINE>` by using the position = 1 predicate:

`<xsl:value-of select="ADR_LINE[1]"/>`

This line then iterates over all the other `<ADR_LINE>` elements except the first one, concatenating them with a space delimiter:

`<xsl:value-of select="string-join(ADR_LINE[position()!=1],' ')"/>`

Comment: You don't need the `string-join` at all, with an XSLT 2 processor and `version="2.0"` a simple `<xsl:value-of select="ADR_LINE[position()!=1]"/>` will output the selected items separated by a space as the default separator, for a different separator you could use the `separator` attribute of `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Thanks Stevangelista and Martin, I will try this approach.

Comment: I tried this but LINE2, LINE3, and LINE4 is having a new line character between them instead of a space.

Comment: Which XSL processor are you using? The separator is a space, not to mention inserting line breaks in text in XML requires a deliberate action.

Comment: Sorry, I did not share the complete XML, ADR_ENTR in my example is an inner aggregate and I am trying to work with `<xsl:for-each select="ADR_LINE">`

Comment: You need to post your full input XML & any existing XSL you're using if the solution needs to be absorbed therein. Both are critical to providing a correct answer.

Comment: @Stevangelista Thanks for your help, I updated my XSLT to incorporate this logic and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ADR_ENTR_VW">
    <ADR_ENTR_VW>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ADR_LINE[1])"/>
            </TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
        <ADR_LINE>
            <TEXT>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string-join(ADR_LINE[position() != 1],' '))"/>
            </TEXT>
        </ADR_LINE>
    </ADR_ENTR_VW>
</xsl:template>
```